# Incompatibilities between ASUS G771JW and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, brightness, display-resolution

I've just bought an ASUS ROG G771JW laptop. I installed Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS here.

I tried installing the driver for the NVIDIA GTX 960M inside it, but after restarting I've got a 640 x 480 pixels resolution which I can't change. Also, I don't have the display brightness adjustment option in the top-bar.

I've read some tutorials on the Internet, but none of them helped. So, how can I properly install the NVIDIA driver for this laptop, and how can I get the ability to adjust display brightness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the latest official drivers that support your NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 960M graphics.

Uninstall the old NVIDIA drivers by executing:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo reboot
```

Install the new NVIDIA drivers by executing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Will this also bring the brightness adjustment option in the top-bar?

Comment: @Victor : Please try it out - every hardware is different - but the newer the laptop is, the more it is recommended to use the latest stable drivers available. This solution worked in most of the cases. :)

Comment: I am installing them now

Comment: It's done. I can see my screen in 1920x1080, but still not able to adjust the brightness from the topbar. What should exactly happen if things went ok?

Comment: I mean I tried to install the NVIDIA drivers hoping tat the brightness keys on my keyboard will start working, but this hasn't happened yet

Comment: @Victor : The brightness key function is hardware vendor dependent and when the keys do not work you will need special drivers from ASUS. But the main problem regarding the screen resolution is solved ... so please do not forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text,
which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) ! :)